# How to fetch WorkItem links with the TFS Java API

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

We use the TFS Java API to fetch WorkItems from a TFS server:

```
    TFSTeamProjectCollection collection = TFSTeamProjectCollectionUtils
            .openTeamProjectCollection(serverUrl, credentials,
                    new DefaultConnectionAdvisor(Locale.getDefault(),
                            TimeZone.getDefault()));
    WorkItemClient client = collection.getWorkItemClient();

    List<WorkItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        WorkItemCollection workItems = client.query(wiqlQuery, null, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < workItems.size(); i++) {
            WorkItem item = workItems.getWorkItem(i);
            result.add(item);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (TECoreException e) {
        throw new ConQATException("Failed to fetch work items from TFS", e);
    }
```

If I run the query `select * from workitems` I get all workitems on the server with all fields and all links. Since I'm only interested in some of the fields, I would like to restrict the query to only those and save some bandwidth/time: `select ID, Title from workitems`

This works fine, but now the links of the items are missing (i.e. `item.getLinks()` always returns an empty collection).

Is there a way to select the links other than `select * from workitems`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around, I found that you can create a link query and run it like this:

```
WorkItemLinkInfo[] infos = client.createQuery("select * from workitemlinks").runLinkQuery()
```

With this, you can get the links as WorkItemLinkInfo objects that contain the IDs of the target and source node and the link type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using WorkItemLinkInfo is correct. 
Just as remark: Using a WIQL Query you only receive the attributes you were querying - which cannot be the set of links of a work item (therefore always empty). If you query a single workitem using

```
WorkItemClient client = TFSConnection.getClient();
WorkItem firstWorkItem = client.getWorkItemByID(id);
```

then you also get the LinkCollection using (containing RelatedLinks, ExternalLinks or HyperLinks)

```
LinkCollection linkcoll = firstWorkItem.getLinks()
```